# Calculate mean values of subsets of a dataframe column and subtract those mean values from a whole dataset where columns match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have the following dataframe:

```
{'Sample': {0: 'AA',
  1: 'AA',
  2: 'AA',
  3: 'AA',
  4: 'AA',
  5: 'AA',
  6: 'AA',
  7: 'AA',
  8: 'AA',
  9: 'AA',
  10: 'BB',
  11: 'BB',
  12: 'BB',
  13: 'BB',
  14: 'BB',
  15: 'BB',
  16: 'BB',
  17: 'CC',
  18: 'CC',
  19: 'CC',
  20: 'CC',
  21: 'CC',
  22: 'CC',
  23: 'CC',
  24: 'DD',
  25: 'DD',
  26: 'DD',
  27: 'DD',
  28: 'DD',
  29: 'DD',
  30: 'DD',
  31: 'DD',
  32: 'DD',
  33: 'DD',
  34: 'DD',
  35: 'DD',
  36: 'AA',
  37: 'AA',
  38: 'AA',
  39: 'AA',
  40: 'AA',
  41: 'AA',
  42: 'AA',
  43: 'AA',
  44: 'AA',
  45: 'AA',
  46: 'AA',
  47: 'AA',
  48: 'AA',
  49: 'AA',
  50: 'AA',
  51: 'BB',
  52: 'BB',
  53: 'BB',
  54: 'BB',
  55: 'BB',
  56: 'BB',
  57: 'BB',
  58: 'BB',
  59: 'BB',
  60: 'BB',
  61: 'BB',
  62: 'BB',
  63: 'BB',
  64: 'BB',
  65: 'BB',
  66: 'BB',
  67: 'BB',
  68: 'BB',
  69: 'BB'},
 'Test No': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 1,
  15: 1,
  16: 1,
  17: 1,
  18: 1,
  19: 1,
  20: 1,
  21: 1,
  22: 1,
  23: 1,
  24: 1,
  25: 1,
  26: 1,
  27: 1,
  28: 1,
  29: 1,
  30: 1,
  31: 1,
  32: 1,
  33: 1,
  34: 1,
  35: 1,
  36: 2,
  37: 2,
  38: 2,
  39: 2,
  40: 2,
  41: 2,
  42: 2,
  43: 2,
  44: 2,
  45: 2,
  46: 2,
  47: 2,
  48: 2,
  49: 2,
  50: 2,
  51: 2,
  52: 2,
  53: 2,
  54: 2,
  55: 2,
  56: 2,
  57: 2,
  58: 2,
  59: 2,
  60: 2,
  61: 2,
  62: 2,
  63: 2,
  64: 2,
  65: 2,
  66: 2,
  67: 2,
  68: 2,
  69: 2},
 'Person': {0: '7A',
  1: '7A',
  2: '7A',
  3: '7A',
  4: '7A',
  5: '7A',
  6: '7A',
  7: '7A',
  8: '7A',
  9: '7A',
  10: '7A',
  11: '7A',
  12: '7A',
  13: '7A',
  14: '7A',
  15: '7A',
  16: '7A',
  17: '9A',
  18: '9A',
  19: '9A',
  20: '9A',
  21: '9A',
  22: '9A',
  23: '9A',
  24: '9A',
  25: '9A',
  26: '9A',
  27: '9A',
  28: '9A',
  29: '9A',
  30: '9A',
  31: '9A',
  32: '9A',
  33: '9A',
  34: '9A',
  35: '9A',
  36: '7A',
  37: '7A',
  38: '7A',
  39: '7A',
  40: '7A',
  41: '7A',
  42: '7A',
  43: '7A',
  44: '7A',
  45: '7A',
  46: '7A',
  47: '7A',
  48: '7A',
  49: '7A',
  50: '7A',
  51: '12B',
  52: '12B',
  53: '12B',
  54: '12B',
  55: '12B',
  56: '12B',
  57: '12B',
  58: '12B',
  59: '12B',
  60: '12B',
  61: '12B',
  62: '12B',
  63: '12B',
  64: '12B',
  65: '12B',
  66: '12B',
  67: '12B',
  68: '12B',
  69: '12B'},
 'Level': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 10,
  5: 10,
  6: 10,
  7: 20,
  8: 20,
  9: 20,
  10: 0,
  11: 0,
  12: 10,
  13: 10,
  14: 20,
  15: 20,
  16: 30,
  17: 0,
  18: 0,
  19: 0,
  20: 0,
  21: 40,
  22: 40,
  23: 70,
  24: 0,
  25: 0,
  26: 0,
  27: 100,
  28: 100,
  29: 200,
  30: 200,
  31: 300,
  32: 300,
  33: 400,
  34: 400,
  35: 400,
  36: 0,
  37: 0,
  38: 0,
  39: 400,
  40: 400,
  41: 400,
  42: 500,
  43: 500,
  44: 500,
  45: 800,
  46: 800,
  47: 800,
  48: 900,
  49: 900,
  50: 900,
  51: 0,
  52: 0,
  53: 0,
  54: 0,
  55: 5,
  56: 5,
  57: 5,
  58: 5,
  59: 7,
  60: 7,
  61: 7,
  62: 7,
  63: 8,
  64: 8,
  65: 8,
  66: 8,
  67: 9,
  68: 9,
  69: 9},
 'Response': {0: 5,
  1: 7,
  2: 4,
  3: 9,
  4: 10,
  5: 14,
  6: 13,
  7: 22,
  8: 25,
  9: 29,
  10: 3,
  11: 2,
  12: 5,
  13: 3,
  14: 12,
  15: 18,
  16: 22,
  17: 10,
  18: 12,
  19: 18,
  20: 12,
  21: 22,
  22: 27,
  23: 57,
  24: 21,
  25: 22,
  26: 32,
  27: 23,
  28: 31,
  29: 45,
  30: 45,
  31: 34,
  32: 54,
  33: 59,
  34: 58,
  35: 57,
  36: 2,
  37: 3,
  38: 1,
  39: 5,
  40: 8,
  41: 7,
  42: 17,
  43: 14,
  44: 19,
  45: 46,
  46: 45,
  47: 43,
  48: 70,
  49: 87,
  50: 67,
  51: 6,
  52: 9,
  53: 1,
  54: 12,
  55: 15,
  56: 22,
  57: 27,
  58: 24,
  59: 47,
  60: 45,
  61: 87,
  62: 67,
  63: 98,
  64: 97,
  65: 99,
  66: 120,
  67: 200,
  68: 230,
  69: 210}}
```

I want to calculate the mean values of Response of where Level = 0, but grouped by Sample, Test No, Person. Then, I want to create a new column, which contains the mean value of the Level 0 subtracted from the Response of the other rows, where the Sample, Test No and Person rows match what the mean value was calculated on for the 0 Level.
Or to put it another way, calculate the mean value of the first set of 0 Levels and subtract it from the next rows down, until the next 0 level it reached, then repeat.

The resulting dataframe would look like this (its no problem if the 0 levels in the new column have values or not):

```
{'Sample': {0: 'AA',
  1: 'AA',
  2: 'AA',
  3: 'AA',
  4: 'AA',
  5: 'AA',
  6: 'AA',
  7: 'AA',
  8: 'AA',
  9: 'AA',
  10: 'BB',
  11: 'BB',
  12: 'BB',
  13: 'BB',
  14: 'BB',
  15: 'BB',
  16: 'BB',
  17: 'CC',
  18: 'CC',
  19: 'CC',
  20: 'CC',
  21: 'CC',
  22: 'CC',
  23: 'CC',
  24: 'DD',
  25: 'DD',
  26: 'DD',
  27: 'DD',
  28: 'DD',
  29: 'DD',
  30: 'DD',
  31: 'DD',
  32: 'DD',
  33: 'DD',
  34: 'DD',
  35: 'DD',
  36: 'AA',
  37: 'AA',
  38: 'AA',
  39: 'AA',
  40: 'AA',
  41: 'AA',
  42: 'AA',
  43: 'AA',
  44: 'AA',
  45: 'AA',
  46: 'AA',
  47: 'AA',
  48: 'AA',
  49: 'AA',
  50: 'AA',
  51: 'BB',
  52: 'BB',
  53: 'BB',
  54: 'BB',
  55: 'BB',
  56: 'BB',
  57: 'BB',
  58: 'BB',
  59: 'BB',
  60: 'BB',
  61: 'BB',
  62: 'BB',
  63: 'BB',
  64: 'BB',
  65: 'BB',
  66: 'BB',
  67: 'BB',
  68: 'BB',
  69: 'BB'},
 'Test No': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 1,
  15: 1,
  16: 1,
  17: 1,
  18: 1,
  19: 1,
  20: 1,
  21: 1,
  22: 1,
  23: 1,
  24: 1,
  25: 1,
  26: 1,
  27: 1,
  28: 1,
  29: 1,
  30: 1,
  31: 1,
  32: 1,
  33: 1,
  34: 1,
  35: 1,
  36: 2,
  37: 2,
  38: 2,
  39: 2,
  40: 2,
  41: 2,
  42: 2,
  43: 2,
  44: 2,
  45: 2,
  46: 2,
  47: 2,
  48: 2,
  49: 2,
  50: 2,
  51: 2,
  52: 2,
  53: 2,
  54: 2,
  55: 2,
  56: 2,
  57: 2,
  58: 2,
  59: 2,
  60: 2,
  61: 2,
  62: 2,
  63: 2,
  64: 2,
  65: 2,
  66: 2,
  67: 2,
  68: 2,
  69: 2},
 'Person': {0: '7A',
  1: '7A',
  2: '7A',
  3: '7A',
  4: '7A',
  5: '7A',
  6: '7A',
  7: '7A',
  8: '7A',
  9: '7A',
  10: '7A',
  11: '7A',
  12: '7A',
  13: '7A',
  14: '7A',
  15: '7A',
  16: '7A',
  17: '9A',
  18: '9A',
  19: '9A',
  20: '9A',
  21: '9A',
  22: '9A',
  23: '9A',
  24: '9A',
  25: '9A',
  26: '9A',
  27: '9A',
  28: '9A',
  29: '9A',
  30: '9A',
  31: '9A',
  32: '9A',
  33: '9A',
  34: '9A',
  35: '9A',
  36: '7A',
  37: '7A',
  38: '7A',
  39: '7A',
  40: '7A',
  41: '7A',
  42: '7A',
  43: '7A',
  44: '7A',
  45: '7A',
  46: '7A',
  47: '7A',
  48: '7A',
  49: '7A',
  50: '7A',
  51: '12B',
  52: '12B',
  53: '12B',
  54: '12B',
  55: '12B',
  56: '12B',
  57: '12B',
  58: '12B',
  59: '12B',
  60: '12B',
  61: '12B',
  62: '12B',
  63: '12B',
  64: '12B',
  65: '12B',
  66: '12B',
  67: '12B',
  68: '12B',
  69: '12B'},
 'Level': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 10,
  5: 10,
  6: 10,
  7: 20,
  8: 20,
  9: 20,
  10: 0,
  11: 0,
  12: 10,
  13: 10,
  14: 20,
  15: 20,
  16: 30,
  17: 0,
  18: 0,
  19: 0,
  20: 0,
  21: 40,
  22: 40,
  23: 70,
  24: 0,
  25: 0,
  26: 0,
  27: 100,
  28: 100,
  29: 200,
  30: 200,
  31: 300,
  32: 300,
  33: 400,
  34: 400,
  35: 400,
  36: 0,
  37: 0,
  38: 0,
  39: 400,
  40: 400,
  41: 400,
  42: 500,
  43: 500,
  44: 500,
  45: 800,
  46: 800,
  47: 800,
  48: 900,
  49: 900,
  50: 900,
  51: 0,
  52: 0,
  53: 0,
  54: 0,
  55: 5,
  56: 5,
  57: 5,
  58: 5,
  59: 7,
  60: 7,
  61: 7,
  62: 7,
  63: 8,
  64: 8,
  65: 8,
  66: 8,
  67: 9,
  68: 9,
  69: 9},
 'Response': {0: 5,
  1: 7,
  2: 4,
  3: 9,
  4: 10,
  5: 14,
  6: 13,
  7: 22,
  8: 25,
  9: 29,
  10: 3,
  11: 2,
  12: 5,
  13: 3,
  14: 12,
  15: 18,
  16: 22,
  17: 10,
  18: 12,
  19: 18,
  20: 12,
  21: 22,
  22: 27,
  23: 57,
  24: 21,
  25: 22,
  26: 32,
  27: 23,
  28: 31,
  29: 45,
  30: 45,
  31: 34,
  32: 54,
  33: 59,
  34: 58,
  35: 57,
  36: 2,
  37: 3,
  38: 1,
  39: 5,
  40: 8,
  41: 7,
  42: 17,
  43: 14,
  44: 19,
  45: 46,
  46: 45,
  47: 43,
  48: 70,
  49: 87,
  50: 67,
  51: 6,
  52: 9,
  53: 1,
  54: 12,
  55: 15,
  56: 22,
  57: 27,
  58: 24,
  59: 47,
  60: 45,
  61: 87,
  62: 67,
  63: 98,
  64: 97,
  65: 99,
  66: 120,
  67: 200,
  68: 230,
  69: 210},
 'Response minus 0': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: 3.75,
  5: 7.75,
  6: 6.75,
  7: 15.75,
  8: 18.75,
  9: 22.75,
  10: nan,
  11: nan,
  12: 2.5,
  13: 0.5,
  14: 9.5,
  15: 15.5,
  16: 19.5,
  17: nan,
  18: nan,
  19: nan,
  20: nan,
  21: 9.0,
  22: 14.0,
  23: 44.0,
  24: nan,
  25: nan,
  26: nan,
  27: -2.0,
  28: 6.0,
  29: 20.0,
  30: 20.0,
  31: 9.0,
  32: 29.0,
  33: 34.0,
  34: 33.0,
  35: 32.0,
  36: nan,
  37: nan,
  38: nan,
  39: 3.0,
  40: 6.0,
  41: 5.0,
  42: 15.0,
  43: 12.0,
  44: 17.0,
  45: 44.0,
  46: 43.0,
  47: 41.0,
  48: 68.0,
  49: 85.0,
  50: 65.0,
  51: nan,
  52: nan,
  53: nan,
  54: nan,
  55: 8.0,
  56: 15.0,
  57: 20.0,
  58: 17.0,
  59: 40.0,
  60: 38.0,
  61: 80.0,
  62: 60.0,
  63: 91.0,
  64: 90.0,
  65: 92.0,
  66: 113.0,
  67: 193.0,
  68: 223.0,
  69: 203.0}}
```

I've thought about creating a new df that contains a subset of the original df based on Response = 0 and then doing a groupby on Sample, Test No and Person, but I don't know how to  'match' the columns in the original df to the subset df to subtract the Level 0 values.

Can anyone please offer me some assistance?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a mask `where` Level is 0. then use it to keep only the Response `where` 0. `groupby` the three columns as wanted and transform the mean to get alignthe mean value for each group, even for the non 0 level. Remove this to the Reponse column and populate our new column only where level is not 0 so the opposite of your mask.

```
m0 = df['Level'].eq(0)
df.loc[~m0, 'Response minus 0'] = (
    df['Response'] 
    - df['Response'].where(m0)
        .groupby([df['Sample'], df['Test No'], df['Person']])
        .transform('mean')
)
print(df)
#    Sample  Test No Person  Level  Response  Response minus 0
# 0      AA        1     7A      0         5               NaN
# 1      AA        1     7A      0         7               NaN
# 2      AA        1     7A      0         4               NaN
# 3      AA        1     7A      0         9               NaN
# 4      AA        1     7A     10        10              3.75
# 5      AA        1     7A     10        14              7.75
# 6      AA        1     7A     10        13              6.75
# 7      AA        1     7A     20        22             15.75
# 8      AA        1     7A     20        25             18.75
# 9      AA        1     7A     20        29             22.75
# 10     BB        1     7A      0         3               NaN
# 11     BB        1     7A      0         2               NaN
# 12     BB        1     7A     10         5              2.50
# 13     BB        1     7A     10         3              0.50
# 14     BB        1     7A     20        12              9.50
# 15     BB        1     7A     20        18             15.50
# 16     BB        1     7A     30        22             19.50
# 17     CC        1     9A      0        10               NaN
# 18     CC        1     9A      0        12               NaN
# ...
```